# Container size doesn't shrink with child scale

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a custom drop down menu in ReactJs. When a user clicks the heading, a list of items appears below it. This works but I want the div that contains both the heading and the list (`.db-container`) to in increase its height depending on if the list (`.db-list`) is visible or not. I can use `display:none`/`block` or `position:absolute`/`relative` with `transform:scaleY(0)`/`scaleY(1)` on `.db-list` but then I cannot animate it or use transitions. I've tried using `visibility:hidden`/`visible` which does hide the list but the container remains its full size.

I am using ReactJs and in the code snippet below, the `handleClick()` function just changes `isVisible` from true to false and vice versa.

```css
.db-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.db-list {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top center;
  position: absolute;
}

.visible-true {
  transform: scaleY(1) !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
```

```html
<div className='db-container'>
  <h3 className='db-name' onClick={handleClick}>Headinf</h3>
  <ul className={`db-list visible-${isVisible}`}>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get `.db-container` to change its height depending on the visibility of `.db-list` and use animations or transitions?

Comment: Have you tried basic `height: auto` instead of the scaling transformation? With `display: none` on the list, the div should shrink to the size of dbname header. Once you toggle display to block, the list should take up more space and hence the auto height will make the container grow. You'll have to use specific values ( 100px, 10%, 4rem, etc ) for the height if you need to transform the height property though. So I would make the base height be the same height as a h1 header, which is about 2rem? 3rem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use max-height and overflow:hidden. These are animatable. Needs a bit of tidying up but you'll get the general idea. Setting max-height means the element will just size itself to the content as long as you set it to a high enough value. (I've made it transform on :hover but you can change it to a click in react)

```
.db-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.db-list {
    max-height:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

.db-name:hover + .db-list {
  max-height:1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shrinking, you can use `position:absolute` then delay your component from re-rendering when hiding for a few millisecond then animate.

I got this problem when I built a custom drawer menu. However, when I hide the component it doesn't animate because you can't animate what you can't see. So I had to delay the component re-render then set `right` to a negative number to move it out of the view port visible part with animation. After that hide the component.

If you use height(to hide by shrinking); it works, but for a second you will see the component children get misplace and it doesn't look great.